# Custom filter in vue 2.0 returns nothing

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue.js

I am trying to build a custom filter that returns the items that match an input. 
It works well with simple arrays such as `['Apple', 'Banana', 'Cupple']`.
but doesn't with an array of objects (I am trying to use this to filter an array that contains user info)

```
 filterBy: function (arr, value) {
              return arr.filter(function(item) {
                item = item.toString();
                  return item.indexOf(value) > -1;
          })

    },
```

in the template I have

```
            <input v-model="userInput" />

            <h2> Customer: </h2>
            <ul v-for="customer in filterBy(customers, userInput)">
                <li>{{customer.name}}</li>
            </ul>
```

EDIT: this is what the data looks like.

```
     "data":[{"id":"9","name":"missy","phone":"21324234532"},     
     {"id":"3","name":"Mahama","phone":"345604542"}]
```

How do I get the customers that match the given input?

Comment: How does your array of objects look like?

Comment: I have added it. I intend to use the phone as the search input, but return the customers name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your array of objects look like this:

```
[
  {"id":"9","name":"missy","phone":"21324234532"},   
  {"id":"3","name":"Mahama","phone":"345604542"},
  {"id":"2","name":"Bernard","phone":"241242542"}
]
```

As been pointed out in comments: `someObject.toString()` will usually return `[object Object]`, so it’s not really useful for filtering anything. You might have expected a JSON output instead, which you could have got using  `JSON.stringify(someObject)`, but a better and accurate approach will be to access that particular key.

You can modify the function like following:

```
 filterBy: function (arr, value) {
              return arr.filter(function(item) {
                  return item.name.indexOf(value) > -1;
          })

    },
```

Comment: wow this is sweet! Thanks. So I needed to go a level deeper to get the particular key I needed?

Comment: @BernardParah `someObject.toString()` will usually return `[object Object]`, so it’s not really useful for filtering anything. You might have expected a JSON output there instead, in which case you would have to do `JSON.stringify(someObject)`. But going directly into the member values is a better way anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the insight! @poke.